# issues with regex that should only match at the beginning of a line or matches too little

Tags: php, css, regex

I wrote this RegEx line:

```
    $dp = preg_replace('/(.*'.$definition.'.*?\s'.$property.':)([^;]*)(.*)/is','$2',$css);
```

which is supposed to extrapolate a value of the property of a CSS definition.
In other words if my CSS is:

```
#mydiv {
    width: 100px;
}
```

$dp is supposed to return '100px' with $definition = '#mydiv' and $property = 'width';

The code seems to work (but let me know if you see something wrong) except for the fact that it also matches 'mydiv' or '.mydiv'. Could you please help me change the code so that if I have $definition = '#mydiv' in ONLY matches #mydiv and not 'mydiv' or '.mydiv'?

I was thinking that since all the $definitions are at the beginning of a new line I could try to change it so it matches ALL of $definition from the beginning of a line but I don't know how to do this and I don't know if it's the best way.
I'm open to suggestions.

The code is supposed to work for all different kind of CSS definitions and properties.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex:

```
^#mydiv\s*{.*?width\s*:\s*([^;]+);.*?}
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: Thanks @Alex but I don't think this will work when #mydiv is in a giant CSS file with CSS definitions before and after it

Answer (score 0):

I still had the issue of 'mydiv' matching both '.mydiv' and '#mydiv' so this morning I came up with this solution which appears to work... I am sure it is not the most correct but it appears to work so I was wondering if you could review it and let me know what you think:

```
function tbs_css_find($definition,$property) { 
global $css; 
$definition_encoded = PostFriendlyCSS_encode($definition); 
echo $definition; 
if ( substr($definition, 0, 1) == '.' ) { 
    $css = str_replace($definition,$definition_encoded,$css); 
    $definition_property_value = preg_replace('/(.*'.$definition_encoded.'.*?\s'.$property.':)([^;]*)(.*)/is','$2',$css); 
} else if ( substr($definition, 0, 1) == '#' ) { 
    $css = str_replace($definition,$definition_encoded,$css); 
    $definition_property_value = preg_replace('/(.*'.$definition_encoded.'.*?\s'.$property.':)([^;]*)(.*)/is','$2',$css); 
} else if ( preg_match('/^\b'.$definition_encoded.'\b/im',$css) ) { 
    $definition_property_value = preg_replace('/(.*^\b'.$definition_encoded.'\b.*?\s'.$property.':)([^;]*)(.*)/ism','$2',$css); 
} else { 
    $definition_property_value = preg_replace('/(.*'.$definition.'.*?\s'.$property.':)([^;]*)(.*)/is','$2',$css); 
} 
return trim($definition_property_value); 
} 

function PostFriendlyCSS_encode($definition) { 
$definition = str_replace('#','%%%pound%%%',$definition); 
$definition = str_replace('.','%%%dot%%%',$definition); 
$definition = str_replace(',','%%%comma%%%',$definition); 
$definition = str_replace(':','%%%semicolon%%%',$definition); 
$definition = str_replace('=','%%%equal%%%',$definition); 
$definition = str_replace('"','%%%quote%%%',$definition); 
$definition = str_replace('[','%%%lbracket%%%',$definition); 
$definition = str_replace(']','%%%rbracket%%%',$definition); 
$definition = str_replace(' ','%%%space%%%',$definition); 
return $definition;  
}
```

To make sure I was only matching 'mydiv' and not '.mydiv' and '#mydiv' I added the \b word-boundry to the preg_replace and the multi-line 'm' modifier AND I am matching for a definition at the beginning of a new line.

I am going with the assumption that every new CSS definition is at the beginning of a new line, as it is in every or most CSS files I've ever seen... so I guess this will break if there is a CSS definition that is not at the beginning of a line but at this point I can't think of a better solution...

of course I am open to suggestions...